# chart js : how to display title or lable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, chart.js

this is my code i didnt display title in chart How do you title the X and Y axis?

```
var barChartData = {
        labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],


    datasets : [
        {
             title: "My First dataset",
            fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
        },
        {
            title: "My First dataset",
            fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
            highlightFill : "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
            highlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
        }
    ]


}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the option add this parameter multiTooltipTemplate:
 "<%= datasetLabel %> - <%= value %>"

Comment: i was add in chart.Bar.js file ? i didnt get it

Comment: change the code  line var barChartData   to var data